# Does the word 'retrospection' have the plural form 'retrospections'?

Tags: grammatical-number

I'm getting mixed results from Internet searches. It looks like plural forms are used, but some dictionaries say "retrospection" is a "mass noun".

Can I use the plural form "retrospections"?

Comment: I'd go with *recollections*, or, in a more arty vein, *retrospectives* (with a subtly different meaning lent it precisely by its use in the arts).

Comment: How would you use the plural form "retrospections"? What meaning do you think it would have? It would be great if you can think of an example sentence showing how you think it could be used. Generally in English, plural forms of abstract nouns like "retrospections" and "imaginations" technically exist, but they sound odd most of the time to native speakers except in specific circumstances. You may have heard that such words "don't have" a plural form: this is a bit of a simplification, but it is actually practical advice for non-native speakers. It's rare for the plural form to sound natural.

Comment: I've been thinking of making a headline for a page, something like 'Ramblings and retrospections'. Would that count as one of those 'specific circumstances'?

Comment: @gues In that case, I recommend *reflections*. The word *retrospections*, even if you could find a way to justify it, is simply awkward.

Comment: Interesting. I'm currently using the word 'reflections' but I had an idea to change it to 'retrospections' because it would precisely be expressing the idea that I wish to communicate. I'd like to sort of fine tune the word 'reflections' to mean "considerations of my past experiences" but I'm not sure how to do this with just one word (or perhaps this word and a very short adjective). 'Retrospections' seemed like an ideal choice.

Comment: Why wouldn't it have a plural form? What does the dictionary say?

Comment: Different dictionaries say different things. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some research based on your preferences.

**From** [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/retrospection)

It is stated that retrospections is indeed not a mass noun and just simply a plural of retrospection.

**retrospection**

English

**Noun**

retrospection ‎(plural retrospections)

**The deliberate recall of past events**

**Example sentences:**

She recognized the retrospections of her students.

**or**

I bring to this conversation, my retrospections of the past...

I hope this was helpful Please let me know if it was

Comment: I've done that search myself and been on that page. However, another page by Oxford dictionary says otherwise: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/retrospection

Comment: That is not directly referring to the word or plural word. It is referring to the other wise English noun so it is still Appropriate to use that plural form

Comment: Is this helpful?

Comment: Here's what other people have done. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=retrospection%2Cretrospections&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cretrospection%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cretrospections%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I'm not sure this is helpful. Some sources say it is okay, some sources say it is not, and the commenters from above say it would sound odd. What is the bottom line of all this?

Comment: I understand and realize this but it is still a word and if it is wanted to be used it can and will be used properly

Comment: I myself had this thought but then again I would like my page not communicate the message that I'm a terrible English speaker and make childish mistakes with it. If on the other hand that use (see the comments below my question) would be proper but just out of fashion as seen today, that would be a different story. If you could give me your opinion please whether my sample sentence (above) would sound in order I'd be helpful.

Comment: Here  is a couple example sentences:

Comment: there you go. Let me know if that helps

Comment: (It's in my edited version of my answer)

Comment: What's your opinion on how 'Ramblings and retrospections' would sound as a title or a headline of a page?

Comment: @chasly from UK: Many thanks for the link! I completely forgot that tool.

Comment: That is perfect. I love how it sounds. it's mysterious but intriguing and exciting. I suggest you go for it (just if you think my answer was helpful, check the check mark to  green on the left of my answer)

Comment: So what is this for because it sounds very interesting

Comment: I've modified the query. It seems that 'restrospections' was used in the past, then was on decline and is on the rise in the most recent years. And there's a reverse picture for 'retrospectives'. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=retrospections%2C+retrospectives&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cretrospections%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cretrospectives%3B%2Cc0

Comment: It's for a headline of my personal blog that I intend to start.

Comment: Interesting. You can be the one to use it and make a change bringing it back to popularity in the modern days. Go for it!